# Influence of rotational degrees of freedom on gas phase stability of ions in CID

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, mass-spectrometry

In mass spectrometry it is possible to determine the stability of an ion in the gas phase using e.g. collision induced dissociation (CID). In CID, we fragment an ion by colliding it with a neutral buffer gas. By gradually increasing the collision energy, it is thereby possible to get a relative measurement of the stability of the ion in the gas phase (so called survival yield analysis).

Now, I have the following question:

The picture below illustrates an effect that is commonly observed in CID namely that bigger ions tend to be more stable as they have more rotational degrees of freedom available to handle the collision energy transferred using CID. This can lead to counterintuitive effects, as for example in this case, one would expect acetic acid to be more acidic (and thus a more stable anion), than propanoic and decanoic acid, but it is the least stable.

[image]

In my work, I wanted to show that increasing chain lengths of the ligand increase the stability of a complex by weak interactions but I don't know how to factor in the effect that the increasing chain length has on the stabilization by the increased rotational freedom. Obviously I want to rule out that the increase in stability is due to the longer chains absorbing the collision energy better. How large could that effect be? Is there any systematic approach to take this effect into account? Is there any literature on the subject?

Comment: I have a number of concerns with your question, and maybe some suggestions. (a) In the definition of the stability of your molecule, you tend to focus on the acidity whereas in a survivor ion analysis, stability is defined relative to the fragmentation pathway (difference between starting product and fragments or starting product and transition state). Thus, unless the fragments or TS are very close in stability, you cannot focus your analysis based purely on the acidity carboxylic acids as the basis of your analysis.

Comment: (b) How do you consider the energy deposition in your molecule? Energy transfer in CID is dependent on the mass of the ion if you do not consider energies in the center of mass reference frame. In the laboratory frame, you will observe a decrease in energy deposition as ion mass increases. This would apply for a single collision conditions. If your conditions are multi-collisional conditions, things get even more complicated.

Comment: (c) The displacement in fragmentation energy as size increases is generally known as "kinetic shift", as it involves a reduction in the fragmentation kinetics when the degrees of freedom of a system increase. I guess that this is what you refer to as the number of rotational degrees of freedom. RRKM theory could probably be used to model this effect, but calculation times would probably scale up rapidly with the size of the systems under study.

Comment: @PLD Right, rotational degrees of freedom is wrong here as the energy will be stored in vibrational modes I should fix that. So there is no generic rule of thumb like a methylene group increases the stability in CID by around this value, right?

Comment: @PLD I guess that besides CID, other fragmentation methods (e.g. IRMPD) will suffer from the same problem, as they are also ergodic processes that will deploy the energy in the vibrational modes. Right? It would be really nice to find a way to determine the gas phase stability for differently sized substituents though. Hmm.

Comment: I see some thermodynamic rules of thumb that could fit, but in this case it is a kinetic effect, so it would also depend on the exact experimental setup (time frame of the fragmentation event). And yes, other activation methods (IRMPD, UVPD, ...) will suffer from similar experimental artefacts. One option that would work would be to allow long fragmentation times such as in an FT-ICR cell, or in the same vein, to use BIRD experiments.

Comment: I see, that makes sense : )

Comment: By the way, for the acidity of carboxylic acids in the gas phase, you should consider having a look at this J. Phys. Chem A article by McMahon et al. http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp9908202 which shows that gas phase acidities of carboxylic acids increase with chain lengths due to intramolecular solvation of the charge.

Comment: @PLD "One option that would work would be to allow long fragmentation times such as in an FT-ICR". I see that then, e.g. in a BIRD experiment, the fragmentation would be controlled by the thermodynamics due to the long time frame. However, wouldn't complexes with larger substituents still be more stable as they are able to uptake a larger amount of energy?

Comment: @deux ex machina From a thermodynamic point of view (infinite time), the only requirement for a fragmentation to take place is that the internal energy is above the activation energy. In the RRKM theory framework, the presence of larger substituents will only translate in a reduced probability of the internal energy to populate the vibration mode leading to the transition state. The difference is really not that larger substituents are able to store more energy (smaller ones can also store large amounts of energy), but a reduced probability for the system to follow the fragmentation pathway.

Comment: @PLD Thanks for all the helpful hints. I guess I will take a look into RRKM theory a bit... The CID results I have gotten really just depend on the size of the substituent and I guess I will try BIRD now. Thanks! : )